# Netezza Streaming ResultSet

Tags: java, database, memory, jdbc, netezza

I am having memory issues because I am trying to read a huge ResultSet from a Netezza database. Does Netezza support any kind of "streaming" ResultSet like MySQL does? If not, will limiting the fetch size like this work instead?:

```
stmt.setFetchSize(50); 
conn.setAutoCommitMode(false);
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the the data once/as you receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pull the rows to store in a file, then your best best is to use a remote external table.

Here is an example that creates a transient remote external table over JDBC.  This will invoke the bulk export/load funciontality provided with the JDBC driver, and create a pipe delimited text file.

```
create external table 'c:\mytest.txt' 
USING (DELIMITER '|' REMOTESOURCE 'JDBC' ) as
select *
from table1;
```

You can call this using conn.createStatement().execute, and you will likely have to add change the file specification to c:\mytest.txt to escape the existing backslash.

You can read more about external tables in the [documentation here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_external_tables.html?lang=en).

You can use setFetchSize, by the way.  I'm not sure that it would solve your memory issue though.

Comment: Aside from exporting to a file as you described above, Netezza does not provide any "streaming" ResultSet options like MySQL does, correct?

Answer (score 0):

From following URL, you can get information about ROWSET_LIMIT, with this variable setting you can limit query result to your requirement and create streams as per need - 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/c_sysadm_user_rowset_limits.html?lang=en

"You can place a limit on the number of rows a query can return and thus restrict resources for large result sets. Specifying a rowset limit when you create a user or a group automatically limits the rows that are returned so that users do not have to append a limit clause to their SQL queries."

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to place limits on the result and create streams manually. Was looking for a more natural solution using batch fetch size, or something similiar.